# WPF set ViewModel of View from DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have been attempting to implement a Sudoku game within a WPF application I am making. I found the [following site](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/855699/Complete-Sudoku-Game-in-Csharp-WPF-Silverlight) that pretty much gave me the perfect starting point to try and add the sudoku to my app.

There is however a major difference which I didn't think much of at first. The code from this site bases everything off a single Window, no UserControls at all, which in itself isn't an issue. However, my current implementation bases the whole content of the app on a ContentControl element.

To skip useless details, here is my MainWindow.xaml file (with everything unrelated to the issue removed):

```
<Window x:Class="BasicGameApp.MainWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BasicGameApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:BasicGameApp.MainWindow.MVVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="700"
        Width="1080"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

I based my UI on this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzP8mw7JUzI) if anyone is curious.

The MainViewModel.cs looks like this:

```
namespace BasicGameApp.MainWindow.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Commands

        public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand SudokuViewCommand { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region ViewModels

        public HomeViewModel HomeVM { get; set; }

        public SudokuViewModel SudokuVM { get; set; }

        #endregion

        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get => _currentView;
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            HomeVM = new HomeViewModel();
            SudokuVM = SudokuViewModel.GetInstance(new SudokuView());

            HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVM;
            });

            SudokuViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = SudokuVM;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the `ObservableObject` `RelayCommand` classes:

```
namespace BasicGameApp.MainWindow.Core
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, everything is programmed correctly and works as intended EXCEPT, the SudokuViewModel. As you can see from the code, the SudokuViewModel isn't instantiated as a public class (this is from the tutorial I stated at the beginning). From that tutorial, the instantiation of the view and associated viewmodel is done as follows in the App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();                           // Instantiate the main window
        mainWindow.ViewModel = ViewModelClass.GetInstance(mainWindow);      // Get an instance of the ViewModel and set the View's ViewModel pointer
        mainWindow.Show();                                                  // Now display the view
    }
}
```

My App.xaml file isn't empty however and contains the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/BasicGameApp.MainWindow;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
            <view:HomeView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SudokuViewModel}">
            <view:SudokuView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Needless to say that the difference between these two setups makes things rather difficult. I attempted to change the DataTemplate to set the ViewModel property on the SudokuView but I can't seem to get it to Bind correctly:

```
<view:SudokuView ViewmModel="{Binding //The calling ViewModel}"/>
```

I'm currently out of ideas as to how I can either adapt the sudoku code to work "without" a viewmodel or adapt the DataTemplate to provide the view with the SudokuViewModel.

Please bare in mind that I am initially an Android developper and this is simply to learn new skills on a personal level.

Comment: It's unclear what these `ViewModel` properties in the MainWindow and the SudokuView are supposed to be good for. You already set the MainWindow's DataContext to a MainViewModel instance in its XAML. The SudokuView's DataContext is automatically set to a SudokuViewModel instance when the appropriate DataTemplate is applied by the ContentControl, i.e. when the CurrentView property is set to SudokuVM.

Comment: Be aware that `Content="{Binding CurentView}"` should be `Content="{Binding CurrentView}"`.

Comment: @Clemens The naming was a typo. It has been corrected and is corrected in code too.

The fact that the `SudokuView` DataContext has been set isn't the issue. The issue is the fact that the property `SudokuView.ViewModel` has to be set to the `SudokuVM` instance which itself requires the view (What is named `MainWindow` in the Sudoku CodeProject link is what I have as `SudokuView` in my solution)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. However, in case you think you really need the ViewModel property, write `<view:SudokuView ViewModel="{Binding}"/>`. It will then get the value of the DataContext. It's obviously redundant, but should work anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and get back to you on how it works out.